# SQL inquiry, tried absolutely everything I know, sql, four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant get this inquiry, tried like every thing

```
 TABLE: ARTIST
 JMBG       NAME        AGE ADRESA
 --------------------------------------
 J1         Ladygaga    35  HOLIVUDHILZ              
 J2         DUSKO       13  BB                       
 J3         EMINEM      40  REVOLUCIJA 5             
 J4         BAGI        22  KURAC                    
 J5         MARKO       33  ULICA                    

 TABLE:HALL
   DID          CAPACITY   CITY
 ---------------------------------
   D1           500        PODGORICA 
   D2           300        NIS       
   D3           1000       BAR       
   D4           2000       NEWYORK   
   D5           750        BEOGRAD   

   TABLE: CITY
  -----------------------------------------
   BAR          montenegro      5000
   BEOGRAD      Serbia          2000000
   BUDVA        montenegro      50000
   NEWYORK      AMERICA         7000000
   NIS          Serbia          1000000
   PODGORICA    montenegro      250000


TABLE: CONCERT
ID         JMBG      HALL
------------------------
K1          J3        D4        
K2          J4        D1        
K3          J1        D1        
K4          J1        D5        
K5          J1        D1        
K6          J3        D1        
K7          J5        D1
```

The inquiry is: Find the countries where the artist with the most held concerts
has performed in. I really did spend a lot of time on this and energy. I would greatly appreciate if someone could do this that has experience, and doesnt find it too difficult.

I tried this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY FROM CITY G, HALL D, CONCERT K
              WHERE K.DID = D.DID AND D.NAZIV = G.NAZIV AND EXISTS(
                SELECT JMBG  FROM CONCERT K1,HALL D1, CITY G1
                        WHERE K.KID=K1.KID 
                        GROUP BY JMBG
                        HAVING COUNT (*) >= ALL(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONCERT
                                                GROUP BY JMBG))
```

Comment: Some recommendations: ditch the old school comma operator for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword. And move the join predicates (conditions) from the `WHERE` clause to the appropriate `ON` clause.

Comment: The specification is bit ambiguous. The "artist that held the most concerts"... does that mean overall count of concerts by the artist, in all countries? Or, are we finding the artist held the most concerts in a particular country? The "inquiry" isn't a clear.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: If you have received a correct answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 5):

Break it down. The artist with the most held concerts...  Which artist had the most held concerts?  (We're going to assume that we're interested in the total number of concerts held overall (in all countries), not the number of concerts held in a particular country.

How many concerts did each artist hold?

```
  SELECT c.jmbg
       , COUNT(1) AS cnt
    FROM concert c
   GROUP BY c.jmbg
```

Which artist held the most concerts?  MySQL and MS SQL Server both have some convenient short cuts we can use here. A question we should ask here, what if there are two or more artists held the *same* number of concerts? Do we want to return both (or all) of those artists, or just return one of them? Which one? (We'd prefer the query to be deterministic... to return the same result given the same rows in the tables.)

Assuming that we want to return just *one* artist that held the most concerts...

For MySQL:

```
  SELECT c.jmbg
    FROM concert c
   GROUP BY c.jmbg
   ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, c.jmbg DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

For SQL Server:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 c.jmbg
    FROM concert c
   GROUP BY c.jmbg
   ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, c.jmbg DESC
```

So that gets us the artist.

The other part of the "inquiry"...  which countries did the artist hold concerts in.

Given a particular artist, we could write a query that performs join operations on the `concert`, `hall` and `city` tables. We'll just take a guess at the name of that first column in the `city` table (since it isn't provided in the question).

```
SELECT i.country 
  FROM city i
  JOIN hall h
    ON h.city = i.cid 
  JOIN concert o
    ON o.hall = h.did
 WHERE o.jmbg = 'Ladygaga'
 GROUP BY i.country
```

---

To combine the two queries, we could use the first as a subquery. My preference is to use an inline view.

```
SELECT g.country 
  FROM city g
  JOIN hall h
    ON h.city = g.cid 
  JOIN concert o
    ON o.hall = h.did
  JOIN (
         SELECT c.jmbg
           FROM concert c
          GROUP BY c.jmbg
          ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, c.jmbg DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) m
    ON m.jmbg = o.jmbg 
 GROUP BY g.country
```

Obviously, there are obviously other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

As I noted in a comment on the question, the specification for this "inquiry" is a bit ambiguous, as to what is meant by "where the artist with the most held concerts has performed in".

There is another interpretation of that specification. If we're interested in getting and analyzing a count of "how many concerts were held in each country by each artist", that's a different query.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

"... not allowed to use `TOP DESC`"

Then just write the query differently. Here's a different way to get the "largest number of concerts held by any artist", and use that to get all the artists that all held that number of concerts.

```
 SELECT n.jmbg
   FROM ( -- largest number of concerts by artist
          SELECT MAX(p.cnt) AS maxcnt
            FROM ( 
                   SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
                     FROM concert d
                    GROUP BY d.jmbg
                 ) p
        ) o
   JOIN ( -- count of concerts by artist 
          SELECT c.jmbg
               , COUNT(1) AS cnt
            FROM concert c
           GROUP BY c.jmbg
        ) n
     ON n.cnt = o.maxcnt
```

Since that has the potential to return more than one row (more than one artist), your outer query may want to return a list of countries for each of the returned artists. That is to say, rather than just `GROUP BY g.country`, you'll likely want to return the artist in the SELECT list, and

```
 GROUP BY m.jmbg, g.country
 ORDER BY m.jmbg, g.country
```

Comment: Im working with SQL server, but i am not allowed to use the commands you used in the part where you mentioned TOP DESC

Comment: Can we just choose artists? (Multiple)

Comment: I am very appreciative of your detailed answer.

Comment: If it is a problem to use multiple artists then, it is alright to assume that only one will have the most concerts held.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic question that looks like coming out of school type of question. This answer will give you some hints but you need to work it out for yourself.

JOIN is your friend, find source below:

[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) - MySQL

[JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx) - SQL Server

What you need to do:

1. join CONCERT table with HALL table by HALL ID
2. join HALL table to CITY table by CITY name
3. sum the count of country appearance or hall capacity (either one you need) grouped by artist
4. order descending by the  sum of count if you need it

Good luck